# Display the typed value to the user but do some calculation in form values React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input box `<Input type='number' onChange={(e) => form.handleChange(e)} />`
When user types in the field I want to show the actual value but in the form value for this field I want to do a calculation like **e.target.value*100**, I am using Formik and Chakra. What will be the suitable way or should do this on submit only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const[value,setValue]=useState(0);
const[calculatedValue,setCalculatedValue]=useState();

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    setCalculatedValue(e.target.value*100)
  };
<Input type='number' onChange={handleChange} value={value}/>
```

sorry for any typos.

Comment: thanx, lol that was easy, I just changed second function setCalculatedValue to form.setFieldValue('fieldname', e.target.value*100) so we won't require second state calculatedValue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const[value,setValue]=useState(0);
const[calculatedValue,setCalculatedValue]=useState();

const handleChange  (e) => {
    setCalculatedValue(e.target.value*100)
  };
```

```html
<Input type='number' onChange={handleChange} value={value}/>
```